# How to implement multiple date format columns on a single table and store it in SPARK

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

a newbie here. I'm trying to find a way to store 2 date columns with ddmmyyyy and mmddyyyy date format in spark. I've gone through customized method but I reckon it supports only 1 format per table. I didn't find a way to store and specify two or more date formats in single table on spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not misunderstood then I believe you are looking for this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
from datetime import datetime

#col1 has date format in DDMMYYY and col2 has date format in MMDDYYYY
df = sc.parallelize([('30082017','08272017'), ('29082017','08262017')]).toDF(["col1", "col2"])

f_mmdd = f.udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m%d%Y'), DateType())
f_ddmm = f.udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d%m%Y'), DateType())
df = df.withColumn("col1_date_ddmm",f_ddmm(df.col1)).withColumn("col2_date_mmdd",f_mmdd(df.col2))
df.show()
```

Output is:

```
+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|    col1|    col2|col1_date_ddmm|col2_date_mmdd|
+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|30082017|08272017|    2017-08-30|    2017-08-27|
|29082017|08262017|    2017-08-29|    2017-08-26|
+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please check the 3rd column and 4th column in the output. I'm stumbling there. I'm not sure if we can change that.

Comment: @bharath what do you really mean by 'not sure if we can change that'? You might need to [elaborate your requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it can be properly translated into code.

Comment: Consider the 1st tuple, I want to get it as 30-08-2017 in 'col1_date_ddmm' and 08-27-2017 in 'col2_date_mmdd' as output.

Comment: See when you ask Spark that a particular column is of `DateType()` then you loose control over how Spark displays it for you and this behavior is pretty logical with any system. But if you simply want to convert your string to a hyphen separated string then you can do like this - `from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, lit; df.withColumn('col1_date_ddmm', concat(df.col1.substr(1, 2), lit('-'), df.col1.substr(3, 2), lit('-'), df.col1.substr(5, 4))); df.withColumn('col2_date_mmdd', concat(df.col2.substr(1, 2), lit('-'), df.col2.substr(3, 2), lit('-'), df.col2.substr(5, 4)));`